# Get Qt path in project file

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I'm executing a script via QMAKE_POST_LINK but need the directory of Qt for that purpose.
Is there a variable holding it or may I retrieve it automatically?

Comment: Why wouldn't you define it (variable) yourself?

Comment: You can set it as an environment variable and get that value in your script.

Comment: You can use environment variable $(QTDIR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
message(Qt version: $$[QT_VERSION])
message(Qt is installed in $$[QT_INSTALL_PREFIX])
message(Qt resources can be found in the following locations:)
message(Documentation: $$[QT_INSTALL_DOCS])
message(Header files: $$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS])
message(Libraries: $$[QT_INSTALL_LIBS])
message(Binary files (executables): $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS])
message(Plugins: $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS])
message(Data files: $$[QT_INSTALL_DATA])
message(Translation files: $$[QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS])
message(Settings: $$[QT_INSTALL_SETTINGS])
message(Examples: $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES])
message(Demonstrations: $$[QT_INSTALL_DEMOS])
```

[qmake Advanced Usage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html#variables)